# error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) and Check50 showing error on credit problem

Tags: c, string, conditional-statements, string-comparison, cs50

To avoid asking multiple question, kindly see the [details and code here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/q/34964/25547) in the cs50 section of **stack**overflow.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. In C you *cannot* compare a string withe the `==`equality operator. So instead of

```
if(... ||(brand == "VISA")
```

use:

```
if(... ||strcmp(brand, "VISA")==0
```